How can one rigorously demonstrate that some function (not bounded) is $ H^1(\Omega)$
Let $\Omega = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2: \sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\frac{1}{2}\}$ be a bounded domain and $v(x,y) = \ln\left|\ln\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right|$. How  to show that $v\in H^1(\Omega)$
I would like to know if my critique below is well-founded or if I am just talking nonsense.
I believe the reasoning presented here is is insufficient. Derivatives were calculated in the classical sense on $\Omega\setminus\{(0,0)\}$, and the conclusion was reached by switching to polar coordinates that $\int_\Omega (D_x v)^2 < \infty$. I find this reasoning suspicious
I think,   it is necessary to show first that  the weak gradient ( derivative in distribution sence) is a function before switching to polar
coordinates like the  link
$\langle\nabla u,\phi\rangle = -\langle u,\nabla\phi\rangle = -\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\int_{\Omega\setminus B_\varepsilon(0)}\ln\left|\ln\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right|\nabla\phi\,dxdy$
But I don't know how to do it.

The question is a few typoes or errors. What is your function v? Do you want H^1 or H^2?

I corrected the confusion of notations thank you

Do you want v or W to be H^1?

i want function $v$. I gave the example of
$w$ to show that the reasoning in the link is suspect

That link is correct. Your v here does not grow fast enough at 0 to produce Dirac mess. If no one answer this I'll do that tomorrow night.

Does the answer below well enough?

@LidingYao  I don't quite understand the result. Please refer to my comment on the 1D example.

Let's try this, for $\epsilon>0$ define $v_\epsilon(x,y)=\ln|\ln\sqrt{x^2+y^2+\epsilon^2}|=-\ln 2+\ln(-\ln(x^2+y^2+\epsilon^2))$. We shall see that $v_\epsilon$ are smooth in $\Omega$ for $\epsilon>0$; and $v_\epsilon\to v$ in $L^2(\Omega)$.
On the other hand
$$\frac\partial{\partial x}v_\epsilon(x,y)= \frac{1}{-\frac 12 \ln (x^2 + y^2+\epsilon^2)} \cdot \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2+\epsilon^2} \cdot 2x.$$
You can check $\frac{\partial v_\epsilon}{\partial x}$ converges to $-\frac x{-\ln(x^2+y^2)\cdot(x^2+y^2)}$ in $L^2$. Similar convergece holds for $\frac{\partial v_\epsilon}{\partial y}$.
This is to say $v_\epsilon$ converges in $H^1(\Omega)$. By uniqueness of the limit $v\in H^1(\Omega)$.

Are you sure about this result: if $ u_n $converges to $u$  in $L^2 $ and $\nabla u_n $ converges to $ w $ in $ L^2 $, then $u_n $ converges to $ u $ in $ H^1 $?

@Noname What is the definition of $H^1$ you are using? Do you know that it is also a Banach space?

It's ok thank you Liding Yao

Here is a standard result you can find in most books dealing with Sobolev spaces:
A function $u \in L^2(\Omega)$ belongs to $H^1(\Omega)$ if and only if $u$ is equal almost everywhere to a function that is absolutely continuous on almost every line segment parallel to the coordinate axes, whose partial derivatives (which are classical) belong to $L^2(\Omega)$.
In your case you have $v(x,y) = \ln (-\frac 12 \ln (x^2 + y^2)) = \ln \frac 12 + \ln(- \ln (x^2 + y^2))$ which is absolutely continuous on every closed line segment in the disk $x^2 + y^2 \le \frac 14$ that does not contain the origin. On each such horizontal line segment you have
$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{-\frac 12 \ln (x^2 + y^2)} \cdot \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2} \cdot 2x.$$ You can verify that $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$ belongs to $L^2$ as in the linked answer using a change of variable to polar coordinates.

Thank you for ur interest. I don't know this result, but how can we prove that $v$ is absolutely continuous on line segments parallel to the axes almost everywhere?

I don't understand this result. Let's take a 1D example: if $v(x) = H(x)$ over $(-1,1)$ where $H$ is the Heaviside function, then $v$ is clearly in $L^2$ and absolutely continuous on any segment not containing the origin (since it's constant there), and its classical derivative is zero except at zero. So, I might wrongly conclude that $v$ is in $H^1$, which is not true.

@LidingYao  Did you read my comment carefully? I mentioned that $H$ satisfies the hypotheses of the theorem mentioned by Umberto, leading to the absurd conclusion that $H \in H^1$.

@Noname Sorry I didn't. It's true that $H'$ is almost everywhere $0$. This principle doesn't say much useful for general distributions. So you are right. But in general people may do similar things because we "already know" $H^1$ behaves well and can avoid similar issues.

@Noname the Heaviside function is not absolutely continuous on every closed subinterval of $(-1,1)$.

@UmbertoP. You also omitted the origin in your reasoning, and I clearly stated that $ H $ is absolutely continuous on any segment not containing the origin. If you don't remove the origin, how do you demonstrate that $v$ is absolutely continuous on lines parallel to the axes?  for the method of
Liding Yao , I need to carefully consider the convergence of  $v_\epsilon$  in $L^2 $ and his dérivatives

The function needs to be AC on almost every line segment parallel to the axes.
